# При отображении в matplotlib графа networkx "обрезаются" части подписей узлов графа. Как это исправить?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

Как видно из итоговой картинки часть подписи узла "обрезается":[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если уменьшить шрифт, то соответственно будет хуже видно надпись.
Код:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

edges = [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3)]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
# получим метки узлов
labels = dict((i, str(i)*10) for i in range(4))

# рисуем граф
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=False)
# рисуем метки
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos, labels=labels)
plt.savefig('labels.png')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку при nx.draw размеры холста как видно автоматически не корректируются, придётся корректировать их вручную, как посоветовали [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453043/networkx-drawing-label-partially-outside-the-box)

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

edges = [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3)]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
# получим метки узлов
labels = dict((i, str(i)*10) for i in range(4))

# рисуем граф
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=False)
# рисуем метки
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos, labels=labels)
x_values, y_values = zip(*pos.values())
x_max = max(x_values)
x_min = min(x_values)
x_margin = (x_max - x_min) * 0.25
plt.xlim(x_min - x_margin, x_max + x_margin)
plt.savefig('labels.png')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно!